# Concatenate the string inside a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am calling a stored procedure in SQL Server from Python. However, There is a union string that needs to be passed in depending on condition in Python.

Here's how the main stored procedure query looks:

```
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT      
    mbh.id,
    COALESCE(oc.DowntimeReasonLevel1Name, 'Nothing for Now') AS 'DowntimeReasonLevel1Name',
    COALESCE(osw.DowntimeReasonLevel2Name, 'Nothing for Now') AS 'DowntimeReasonLevel2Name',
    CAST(SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, de.start_time, de.end_time))/60.0 AS decimal (8,2)) as Duration
FROM    
    mixer_downtime_event mde
JOIN 
    downtime_event de ON de.id = mde.downtime_event_id
JOIN 
    oee_status_word osw ON osw.id = de.oee_status_word_id
JOIN 
    oee_category oc ON oc.id = osw.oee_category_id
JOIN 
    mixer_batch_history mbh ON mbh.id = mde.mixer_batch_history_id
JOIN 
    compound_process cp ON cp.id = mbh.compound_process_id
JOIN 
    compound c ON c.id = cp.compound_id
WHERE 
    mde.mixer_batch_history_id IN (@IdList)
    AND osw.id <> 9000
    AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, de.start_time, de.end_time) > 0
GROUP BY 
    mbh.id, DowntimeReasonLevel1Name, DowntimeReasonLevel2Name
--+
--@downtimeUnion
END
```

The union query could be something like:

```
UNION 
    SELECT  'Changeover' AS 'DowntimeReasonLevel1Name',
    'Changeover' AS 'DowntimeReasonLevel2Name',
    %f as Duration
```

or could be blank string.

How do I join this query together inside the stored procedure?

Comment: You can't.  Your existing query has four columns and your passed in values only account for three.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, sorry, Forgot to update that portion of the query, I am not using mbh.id so it will eventually have the same number of columns on both end.!! The trouble I have is with the concatenation of the whole UNION part with main query. Since, it has to be completely dynamic ! (As per condition I can either have Changeover or trials or etc as column)

Answer (score 0):

Pass in the `@Duration` as a parameter and just add:

```
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL,
       'Changeover' AS DowntimeReasonLevel1Name,
       'Changeover' AS DowntimeReasonLevel2Name,
        @Duration as Duration
```

If you want this to be conditional, then you can let `@Duration` do double duty as a flag for conditionality:

```
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL,
       'Changeover' AS DowntimeReasonLevel1Name,
       'Changeover' AS DowntimeReasonLevel2Name,
        v.Duration as Duration
FROM (VALUES (@Duration)) v(Duration)
WHERE v.Duration IS NOT NULL;
```